# Sending JSON object to WCF Rest Service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, rest

I am trying to get my application working by using REST, WCF and JSON (new to all those technologies). I have the 'GET' working fine. It is the 'POST' that is causing me problems.

As you will see below I 'pack up' my JSON using JSON.stringify, then fire off the POST to the REST resource. However, when the object gets to the WCF method that is handling the request the object is always null.

Here is the code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       var input = {
           Customer: {
               customerId: "1",
               firstname: "luke",
               lastname: "sayaw",
               email: "lumsayaw@gmail.com",
               mobile: "0433395106",
               state: "QLD"
           }
       };

       $.ajax({
           url: 'http://local.rest/restservice.svc/getcustomer',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify(input),
           dataType: 'json',
           type: 'POST',
           async: true,
           success: function (data, success, xhr) {
               alert('Group saved - ' + data);

               alert('first name: ' + data.firstname);



           },
           error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               alert('Error! - ' + xhr.status + ' ' + error);
           }
       });

   });
```

And the server side codes:

```
namespace RestService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "RestService" in code, svc and config file together.

public class RestService : IRestService
{

    public string getcustomer(Customer Customer)
    {
        string id = Customer.customerId ;
        return new JavaScriptSerializer ().Serialize (Customer );
    }
}


[DataContract ]
public class Customer
{
    public string customerId {get;set;}
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }

}

}
namespace RestService
{


[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/getcustomer")]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Customer")]
     string getcustomer(Customer Customer);
}
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: What is the output of `JSON.stringify(input)`?

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the RequestFormat also? `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`

Comment: the output of JSON.stringify was Customer data in json format..

Comment: public string getcustomer(Customer Customer) always returns null.

Comment: i have posted the customer data in json format correctly..but the server side method returns null object

Comment: [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare  ,
        UriTemplate = "customers/getcustomer")]
        string getcustomer(Customer Customer);

Comment: I have spent several hours on this but still not able to resolve it.

Comment: Try using a message inspector (IDispatchMessageInspector) to check what arrives at the service side and troubleshoot further. If nothing arrives to the server it is most likely some bug on the client side, otherwise likely a JSON deserialization issue.

Comment: thanks. I was missing [DataMember] attribute on each property of the Customer class. it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetJson", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)] //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
Stream GetJSON(); 

....
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
```